# how to choose an android emulator that match real device

Tags: android, size, emulation, resolution, adjustable

I have created an app that works on 10.1 inch tablet. Later I get a 7 inch one and that need some change to adjust for font size ( font as big as in a big screen and also a smaller screen). Now I get a RedMi note phone that is 5.5 inch. The app looks badly and needs big change of the UI screen. What are the best way to adjust for such changes in screen size and resolution?

Also, how should I create an emulator that meet the real device resolution and screen size? How should I pick when there are no one nexus device that match it completely?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge for making all screen compatibility application.

For example,

```
layout - Mobile screen
layout-large - Tablet below 7 inch
large-xlarge - Tablet above 7 inch
```

refer this link for more details http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For creating the new emulator device, Goto eclipse and

```
Window->Android virtual device manager->Device defination(tab)->Select device->Create device-> restart the eclipse
```

The you can see the created device.